# Eliminar filas repetidas según una columna manteniendo solo la fila con máximo valor en otra columna

Tags: python, pandas, data, datarow

Tengo un DataFrame con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es eliminar las filas duplicadas que contengan el mismo valor en la columna `VC_CODASIG` pero quedándome con la fila que tiene el máximo valor en la columna `NOTA_FINAL`. En caso de tener dos valores iguales como nota final, me debo quedar solo con uno, por ejemplo *441407* que como observamos se repite dos veces (en la columna 6 está la cantidad de veces que cada `VC_CODASIG` se repite).

En la imagen los que esta del mismo color se repiten y el color verde significa que solo me debo quedar con ese valor.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más directa es usar [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) usando el argumento `keep` para mantener una de las filas en vez de eliminarlas todas. La clave está en **ordenar previamente el DataFrame por la columna `NOTAFINAL`**.

Por ejemplo, si ordenamos de forma ascendente según `NOTAFINAL` podemos aplicar `drop_duplicates(subset='VC_CODASIG', keep='last')`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'VC_CODASI': (441407, 441407, 241404, 341401, 241404, 341401,
                          241410, 341406, 241410, 141409, 341404, 241410),
            'NOTAFINAL': (0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 1.0, 6.4, 5.2,
                          2.8, 5.7, 5.4, 1.4, 5.3, 0.5)}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df

    NOTAFINAL  VC_CODASI
0         0.0     441407
1         0.0     441407
2         3.9     241404
3         1.0     341401
4         6.4     241404
5         5.2     341401
6         2.8     241410
7         5.7     341406
8         5.4     241410
9         1.4     141409
10        5.3     341404
11        0.5     241410

>>> df.sort_values('NOTAFINAL', inplace=True)
>>> df.drop_duplicates('VC_CODASI', keep="last", inplace=True)
>>> df.sort_index(inplace=True) 
>>> df

    NOTAFINAL  VC_CODASI
1         0.0     441407
4         6.4     241404
5         5.2     341401
7         5.7     341406
8         5.4     241410
9         1.4     141409
10        5.3     341404
```

Answer (score 0):

La opción de @FJSevilla funciona perfectamente. La  opción alternativa sería usar `groupby`.
En ese caso el código iría así:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'VC_CODASI': (441407, 441407, 241404, 341401, 241404, 341401,
                      241410, 341406, 241410, 141409, 341404, 241410),
        'NOTAFINAL': (0.0, 0.0, 3.9, 1.0, 6.4, 5.2,
                      2.8, 5.7, 5.4, 1.4, 5.3, 0.5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.sort_values('NOTAFINAL', ascending=False).groupby(['VC_CODASI']).head(1).sort_index()
```

La diferencia inmediata es que este sistema te deja quedarte sólo con la mejor o con cuantas necesites (canviando `head`) y agrupar sólo por `VC_CODASI` o por varias columnas.